# How to check the last time a database table updated

Tags: sql-server, database

In Sql Server,there is a table called 'Product'

Is there any way to check the recent time/last time ,when data was populated in 'Product' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` to figure out when was the table updated last time.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'Database_Name_Here')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('Table_Name_here')
```

If WHERE condition is entirely removed it will provide details of the entire database.

Refer this [link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('DbName')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```

This will give you the details when the table was last updated.